# How to save session after logging in using Passport and Express JS?

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, axios, passport.js

I am creating a node backend with express and I am using Passport for authentication. I have a `/login` to login route and a `/me` route to get the currently logged in user.

This is my code for these routes.

```
//auth_routes.js
const express = require('express');
const { Users } = require('../database/models');

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } });
    if (!user) {
      res.status(401).send("Wrong username and/or password");
    }
    else if (!await user.correctPassword(req.body.password)) {
      res.status(401).send("Wrong username and/or password");
    }
    else {
      console.log("LOGIN", req.sessionID)
      req.login(user, err => {
        (err ? next(err) : res.json(user))
      });
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});


router.get('/me', (req,res) => {
  console.log("ME SESSION", req.sessionID)
  if (req.user) {
    res.json(req.user);
  } else {
    res.status(401).send("Not logged in");
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I initialize passport like so:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const passport = require('passport')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const session = require('express-session')

const db = require('./database')
const api_routes = require('./routes/api_routes')

const SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store)
const sessionStore = new SequelizeStore({ db })
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

passport.serializeUser((user,done) => {
  console.log("in serialize", user.id)
  return done(null,user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id,done) => {
  console.log("in deserialize", id)
  try {
    const user = await db.models.Users.findByPk(id);
    done(null,user);
  } catch (err) {
    done(err);
  }
});

const configureApp = () => {
    app.use(cors({origin:'http://localhost:3001',credentials: true}));
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, X-Response-Time, X-PINGOTHER, X-CSRF-Token,Authorization');
      if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
          return res.status(200).end();
      } else {
          next();
      }
  });
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
    app.use(morgan('dev'))

    app.use(
      session({
        secret: process.env.SECRET || "SUPER SECRET",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: sessionStore,
        cookie: {secure: false}
      })
    )
    app.use(passport.initialize())
    app.use(passport.session())
    app.use('/api', api_routes)

    app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
      console.error(err);
      console.error(err.stack);
      res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.message || "Internal server error");
    })
}

const startListening = () => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on PORT ${PORT}`))
}

const syncdb = async () => {
  await db.sync({force: true});
}

const bootApp = async () => {
  await sessionStore.sync();
  await syncdb();
  await configureApp();
  await startListening();
}

bootApp();
```

I find that when I use postman to send the post request to `/login` and the get request to `/me`, everything works as expected and the session IDs are the same between both requests. But when I log in from the frontend, the user is logged in and gets a response, but it gets a 401 error back from the get request to `/me` and the session IDs are different between login request and the me request.

This is client-side code (redux + axios):

```
export const login = login => async dispatch => {
  try {
    let { data } = await axios.post('http://lacolhost.com:5000/api/auth/login', login);
    console.log(data);
    dispatch({type: 'SAVE_RESPONSE', payload: data});
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error logging in", err);
    dispatch({ type: 'SAVE_RESPONSE', payload: { message: 'Error communicating with server' }});
  }

export const getUser =  () =>  async (dispatch) => {
    try {

      const { data } = await axios.get('http://lacolhost.com:5000/api/auth/me', {withCredentials: true})
      dispatch({
        type: 'SELECT_USER',
        payload: data
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

What could cause this discrepancy and how do I resolve this error? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make API requests on your front-end, add the {withCredentials: true} config if you're using axios.